# Some Emails Never Arrive - Outlook 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook

A couple of my users are experience an issue where emails do not arrive in their inboxes.  I can track the message on the servers and see a DELIVER event, which I assume means it has gone through to mailbox. The spooky thing is that the email never appears in the Inbox of the user.

I have gone through all the rules on the users' accounts and nothing would account for the messages that do not arrive.  I set up forwarding in Exchange (03 and 07 servers), and the emails come through to the forward mailbox.  I created a new mailbox for a user and assigned her aliases to mailbox and, thus far, it appears that all messages are going through.

Does anyone have any ideas for troubleshooting this?

Thanks!

[Update]
Trying deleting and importing rules following: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924297

Answer (score 2):

We just had this exact situation the other day and it turned out that the user had a POP3 client running at the same time as Outlook 2007, that would pull off the email before the user saw it in Outlook. This took hours to finally resolve.

...Michael

Comment: +1 this happens all. the. time.  "Pop client? No. Never.  Not at all.  Well I might have left Thunderbird running at home..." ... faceplant.